# AudioInput stream cannot open .wav file

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to play a simple `.wav` file but I get the error "could not get audio input stream from input URL"
Here is my code:

```
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("click.wav");
        if (url == null) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find the file");
        }
        else {
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

And I dragged the file `click.wav` into my project

Comment: Which specific exception do you get? That's only the message, you should paste the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned my project and it worked

Comment: Eheheh, classic Eclipse!